# using jquery as an alternative to css nth child

Tags: jquery, css, parent-child

I am using the following css to create list items with a chckerboard background ( every other list item has a grey background, which shift every row to create a checkerboard pattern:

```
li:nth-child(8n+2), li:nth-child(8n+4), li:nth-child(8n+5), li:nth-child(8n+7) {
    background-color:grey;
}
```

Is there way I can do this using jquery that is  more supportive than css3? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: **yes!**

Just use it as a selector inside a `document.ready` and it'll work cross-browser, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("li:nth-child(8n+2), li:nth-child(8n+4), li:nth-child(8n+5), li:nth-child(8n+7)")
    .css('background-color','grey');
});
```

Note: this runs on the elements present **when it's run**, if you're dynamically adding/removing elements, just call the same selector/`.css()` then.  I'd recommend a class in this case though, so instead of `.css('background-color','grey')`, you'd have `.addClass('myClass')`